# Creating a method that can return two different things

Tags: java

im trying to make a method that can return two different things based on the type of data that is fed into it.

this class changes the random item to type of data it is

this is what I have, I am aware that in this method that all it is allowed to return is a resource but I'm not sure how to make it that it can return wither a resource or junk.

```
public Resource itemToResourceOrJunk(randomItem d){
    Resource i;
    Junk O;
    i = d.getResource();
    O = d.getJunk();

    if(d.resourceName.equals("notassigned")){
        return o;
    }
    else if(d.junkName.equals("notassigned")){
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not very elegant to simply return object. Is there any relationship or commonality between junk and Resource, so allow you to use an interface or base class that can be returned?

Comment: I would recommend `Resource` and `Junk` to both extend/implement a common attribute, then simply have `getData()`

Comment: Time to rethink the approach...

Comment: This smells like a bad design. After you invoke it and receive whatever object it returns, what are you going to do with it? Probably check if it's a `Resource` or a `Junk` and then do something with it - so what good did this method do? You still have to re-check the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Resource and Junk implement an interface and use that as the return value.

So

```
public class Resource implements ResourceOrJunk {
...
}
```

and

```
public class Junk implements ResourceOrJunk {
...
}
```

interface:

```
public interface ResourceOrJunk {
//can be left empty, or add some shared methods
}
```

now you can change the method to:

```
public ResourceOrJunk itemToResourceOrJunk(randomItem d){
```

and calling methods can check the result:

```
ResourceOrJunk roj = itemToResourceOrJunk(d);
if (roj instanceof Resource){
    Resource r = (Resource)d;
    //do stuff with resource
} else {
    Junk j = (Jurk)d;
    //do stuff with junk
}
```

Comment: i did this and now its says that Resource cannot be cast to randomItem same as the Junk can not be cast to randomItem

Comment: Where are you casting junk or resource to randomItem? I didnt put that anywhere in my example and neither did you.

Comment: i put it in a bag class which i want to be able to hold both of the items Resource and Junk

Answer (score 4):

You could have both `Resource` and `Junk` implement same interface (say `Stuff`), and then make the return type `itemToResourceOrJunk` to be that interface.

To be clear, it could go this way:

```
public class Resource implements Stuff { ... }
```

and

```
public class Junk implements Stuff { ... }
```

then

```
public Stuff itemToResourceOrJunk(randomItem d){ ... }
```

**Though if you need to use methods or properties that are specific to either** `Resource` **or** `Junk`, **then you'd have to cast to the relevant type.**

Answer (score 2):

You could change your method to return Object:

```
public Object itemToResourceOrJunk(randomItem d){
    ...
}
```

Then the caller would have to use `instanceof` to figure out what type of object was actually returned.

Answer (score 2):

Make both Resource and Junk implement the same interface (or extend the same class) then use that as the return type.